# How do I pass data types that are not object as Model for the Form in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor, blazor-editform

In the Blazor's **EditForm** tag there is a required attribute "Model" and it expects an object. Is there a way to pass a Tuple or any other data type to this Model attribute instead of object?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in .NET is an object, so you can literally pass anything.